# Redis : Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: unable to bind socket, errno: 13

Tags: docker, redis

```
# develop.yml
  redis:
    image: redis
    command: redis-server --requirepass 123
    ports:
    - '6379:6379'
    expose:
    - "6379
```

`docker-compose -f develop.yml up redis` shows:

```
docker-compose -f develop.yml up redis
Starting django-blog_redis_1 ... done
Attaching to django-blog_redis_1
redis_1     | 1:C 16 Nov 2018 03:52:46.935 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_1     | 1:C 16 Nov 2018 03:52:46.935 # Redis version=5.0.1, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_1     | 1:C 16 Nov 2018 03:52:46.935 # Configuration loaded
redis_1     | 1:M 16 Nov 2018 03:52:46.935 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: unable to bind socket, errno: 13
```

I check the port:
`fuser -k -n tcp 6379`
but nothing use 6379.

How can I solve it?

Comment: By chance do you have something else running on port 6379?

Comment: @R.A.Lucas no, I even restart the system, nothing running on port 6379

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My os: Deepin Linux.

It seems that the problem is with deepin.

Execute the following command to solve it:

```
sudo apt remove apparmor
```

Related discussion: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/413

Comment: Still the same problem with the latest stable Deepin nowadays.